# Change angular material input style

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to change the style of a angular material input.

So far I managed to change the `background-color` using :

```
md-input-container {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

The placeholder and label color using :

```
md-input-container.md-default-theme label,   
md-input-container.md-default-theme .md-placeholder {  
    color: #FDFE67 !important; 
}
```

But I can't manage to change the line color under the text when we `focus` the input and the text color when we type in the input.

Here is the html input :

```
<md-content>
    <md-input-container>
        <label>{{isEnglish ? 'Search...' : 'Recherche...'}}</label>
           <input ng-model="searchInput" id="sInput" 
                  ng-change="filterCartoList(searchInput)" my-enter="filterCartoList(searchInput)">
    </md-input-container>
</md-content>
```

**Edit:** I managed to change the text color when typing this way :

```
md-input-container .md-input {
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.87);
border-color: rgba(254,253,103,0.82);
}
```

Comment: make a fiddle, this way is not clear and cannot help

Comment: Just change the color of existing material input we can find there : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.input

After seing their example, "line color under the text when we focus the input and the text color when we type in the input." should be more clear to you, you can directly export their example to codepen.

I also added the html input in the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the CSS selector used by Angular Material:

```
md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid).md-input-focused .md-input {
    border-color: your_color_here;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know where to find those selectors in their doc :(

Comment: I just inspected using chrome dev tools

Comment: Well, I didn't manage to inspect the focused element. Was looking into it when u posted actually

Answer (score 1):

```
<md-input-container style="position: relative; top:19px;">
                              <label style="border-color: white; color: white;">Email</label>
                              <input style="border-color: white; color: white;" >
                              </md-input-container>
```