# How do I customize the styles within an Angular Material Input?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I am working with a freelance client on the side that wants to utilize Angular Material throughout the project. However, they do not like the way that the underline looks in the angular material input. I have tried a variety of approaches to change this, but I haven't found any success yet.

To be honest, I haven't even been able to find the tag in the DOM that would let me alter that border.

[Here](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples) are the Angular Material docs, as you can see all of the available options have at least some form of a bottom border.

Some approaches I've tried:

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585442/change-angular-material-input-style) is from the old angular material and no longer works for the new angular material
- The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310392/angular-material-mdinput-border-around-the-control) is for the new angular material, but I was not able to get it to work. I implemented exactly as described and no styling changed.
- [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786787/how-to-change-mat-form-field-border-color-in-angular-material) looked like it would work. Unfortunately, I could not get it to work either.

Any help or input on this topic would be appreciated.

For reference, the client said that any changes that deviated from the desired design would be denied. So I have to get this to work. I believe I could maybe, possibly lobby to build a custom input component as a solution, but I know that they are dead set on Angular Material.

Edit. Added a pic of desired look:

[image]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what you would like the behavior to be? How would you like it to look? Pic would be very helpful if possible.

Comment: I attached a pic at the bottom. Behavior is the same. All I need is to change the style that Ang Material is applying, which isn't the point of Ang Material. But what the client wants the client gets.

Answer (score 0):

this little code did it for me. I didn't want to display it and just set height and width to 0.

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline{
height:0 !important;
width:0  !important;
}
```

However I think its kinda hard to style the Angular Material Components and for me its sometimes better to built my own.

Comment: My understanding based on other similar issues on stackoverflow is that ::ng-deep is deprecated in the latest versions.

Comment: Acutally I am using latest version of Angular and Angular Material. Did you try to use it? If you get anohter solution pls also post it. I am searching for a better solution for quite some time and i want to learn something as well.

Comment: I am using Angular 5 and the latest version of Angular Material. I tried this approach along with about 6 or 7 others, unfortunately I couldn't get it to play nicely with Ang Mat. My current solution was to create a CSS directive that would add the styling that my client wanted, although this did take away some of the nice animations that Ang Mat utilizes. Hopefully I'll come across another solution that can help me, but as of right now this was the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need a .scss to be imported either within the default theme.scss or after the import of the material stylesheet in main.scss.

Now, Material offers you the option of customising colours and some of the styles by overriding their `@mixins` found somewhere in the Material folder ( I don't have the folder in front of me.. very sorry for the vague pointing... ).

Back to the newly added file; You can override material's default styling by checking the DOM for certain classes and then adding them in said file with the desired changes. Because the file is loaded after Material's, the default styling in overridden. Same thing applies for the `@mixin` you chose to override. Just have a look in the file, copy-paste the whole `@mixin` and change accordingly.

Now if you wish to go even further, my colleagues and I have a custom library that uses Material BUT the whole styling is stripped off leaving you with the bear input within the mat-form-group and then using a `<input disabled/>` with a `position:absolute` over it. That way you get to benefit from material without using their style.

Comment: I'll charge ahead down this path and see what I can do. I don't really want to go to the extreme of overriding all of the styles, if that's my only other option I am confident I can convince the client to allow me to use a custom component.